# How to Change my DNS

Tags: dns

Every time I browse internet one my computer in my network it connects to US DNS server. I changed my DNS server to google DNS and ISP DNS still it connects to US server how to change this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Flush your local DNS cache
   On Windows: Start-Run cmd.exe
   at the prompt, type:

   ipconfig /flushdns

if that doesn't work...

2. Wait about an hour....sometimes it takes a while to propogate

Comment: it works any specific reason does this happens ?

Comment: DNS records are, for the most part, static bits of data...meaning they don't change very often.  Knowing this, the Microsoft OS creates a small list of DNS entries locally rather than looking up the addresses for every request. The ipconfig executable can be used to do many network related things, one of which is to clear out that local cache.  Glad it worked, please mark the answer as correct.